# Two measures in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ (finite measure)   and $m$ (Lebesgue measure) be two finite measures in   $(K, \mathscr{M})$ with $\mathscr{M}$ the borelian family where $K$ is a compact in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Let $A, B \subseteq K$ such that $\mu (K\setminus A) = 0 =\mu(K \setminus B)$.

If $m(A) >0$ then $m(B)> 0$ ?

I think that it's false, but I can't give a counterexample.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False. Here's the most stupid example I can come up with: take $K$ with $\mathfrak{m}(K)>0$ and $p \in K$. Consider the point mass $\delta_p$, which is a finite measure over the Borel sets in $K$.

Now take $A = K$ and $B = \{p,q\}$ with $q \neq p$. Then $\delta_p(K\setminus A) = \delta_p(\varnothing) = 0$ and $\delta_p(K \setminus \{p,q\}) = 0$, but $\mathfrak{m}(A) = \mathfrak{m}(K) > 0$ and $\mathfrak{m}(B) = \mathfrak{m}(\{p,q\})= 0$.

Comment: If we suppose $A \neq K$ and $B \neq K$. What I can do to obtain the same false result ? Thanks

Comment: You can take $A$ to be any subset of $K$ with positive Lebesgue measure, containing $p$.

Comment: Also, you can be more extreme and take $B = \{p\}$, it'll work too.